# How to read 1/4 audio jack data sheet?

Tags: audio, guitar-amplifier

I am trying to layout my own pcb for a guitar amp similar to

[image]

but I am confused how the IN symbol that corresponds to the audio jack is supposed to be connected.

[Switchcraft Inc. RN112BPC](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/switchcraft-inc/RN112BPC/SC1123-ND/109625)

[image]

I am neither sure which connection configuration shown is appropriate or which pin corresponds to which. If you know of a 1/4 inch jack with better datasheets that explain how to connect it, that would also help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have the wrong jack.  The RN112BPC is a stereo jack; the one in the schematic is a mono jack with a switched lead, which is the [RN112APC](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/barrel-audio-connectors/1443095?k=&pkeyword=&pv272=45&FV=ffec10d2) on the right:

[image]

I agree, the documentation for this is terrible.  On another site, I was able to find a little picture, and another, a [labeled board layout](http://datasheet.octopart.com/RN-112APC-Switchcraft-datasheet-76366.pdf):

[image]

Note the board layout is upside down, as it shows the pins as if you were looking down at the board.  So you have to flip it in order to locate the pins on the bottom of the jack.

A mono jack, used in a guitar, has just a Sleeve and Tip connection (if it was stereo, the Ring connection would be the other channel).  The Tip Shunt connection is the switched lead, not used in your case.

[image]

Comment: Still a bit uncertain, so just to be clear the sleeve in this diagram is connected to ground and the tip is connected to the gate and resistor node?

Comment: @Bob Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @Bbb EM Fields has a good suggestion in his answer, if you want to implement it, just tie the Tip Shunt (the pin next to Tip) to the Sleeve (ground).

Answer (score 2):

The jack shown on your schematic is an RN112APC, and the switched pin (the one with the arrow) should be grounded so that when there's no guitar plugged in, the amp's input will be shorted to ground per the edited schematic, following, which will kill any noise appearing across R1.
[image]

Comment: That's a good suggestion, all the OP has to do is tie the Tip Shunt pin to the Sleeve.

Comment: Warning, I think there is a bug in the schematic, C1 cannot be 47n, maybe is 47u

Comment: C1 is reasonable.  It forms a high pass together with R3. Cutoff around 300Hz.  The output of a guitar pickup isn't necessarily flat.  Besides which, the amplifier of a guitar is part of the instrument.  It **forms** the sound.  Its job **isn't** faithful reproduction of an existing sound.  Its job is "make a sound that the player likes.